# undefined variable when i use mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in mysqli. I was using mysql and converting it in mysqli. When the data in my database are empty the error showed up and said " Undefined variable: candidate_name_5" but in mysql when the data in mydatabase is empty it still works. I dont know whats the problem. Its working fine in mysql but many errors in mysqli. Please help me what is the problem

```
 <?php
 require('connection.php');
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','smart_id_user');
// retrieving candidate(s) results based on position
if (isset($_POST['monthReport'])){   
/*
$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates where candidate_name='Luis Nani'");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
  {
  $candidate_1=$row1['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
 */
 $monthReport = $_POST['monthReport'];

$results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM voting_tbCandidates where candidate_position='$monthReport'");

$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($results); // for the first candidate
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results); // for the second candidate
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row7 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row8 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row10 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row11 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

  if ($row1){
  $candidate_name_1=$row1['candidate_name']; // first candidate name
  $candidate_1=$row1['candidate_cvotes']; // first candidate votes
  }

  if ($row2){
  $candidate_name_2=$row2['candidate_name']; // second candidate name
  $candidate_2=$row2['candidate_cvotes']; // second candidate votes
  }
  if ($row3){
    $candidate_name_3=$row3['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_3=$row3['candidates_cvotes'];

  }
  if($row4){
    $candidate_name_4=$row4['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_4=$row4['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
  if($row5){
    $candidate_name_5=$row5['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_5=$row5['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
  if($row6){
    $candidate_name_6=$row6['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_6=$row6['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
  if($row7){
    $candidate_name_7=$row7['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_7=$row7['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
  if($row8){
    $candidate_name_8=$row8['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_8=$row8['candidate_cvotes'];
  }
  if($row9){
    $candidate_name_9=$row9['candidate_name'];
    $candidate_9=$row9['candidate_cvotes'];
      }
}
   else
        // do nothing
?> 
 <?php
// retrieving positions sql query
 $positions=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM voting_tbPositions")
 or die("There are no records to display\n" . mysqli_error()); 
     ?>
  <?php
 session_start();
  //If your session isn't valid, it returns you to the login screen for 
protection//
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){

 }
 ?>

 <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport']))
 {$totalvotes=$candidate_1+$candidate_2+$candidate_3+$candidate_4;} ?>
 <html><head>
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
   <a href="student.php">HOME</a>
  <a><hr></a>
  <a href="vote.php">VOTE</a>
  <a><hr></a>
  <a href="refresh.php">POLL RESULTS</a>
  <a><hr></a>
  <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; 
</span>

<script language="JavaScript" src="js/admin.js">
</script>
</head><body bgcolor="tan">
  <center>
 <font color = "white" size="7"> <div id="hihi">ONLINE VOTING SYSTEM</div></font>

 <br><br>

<br>
 <br></center>
 <div id="page">

<div id="header">
 <h1>POLL RESULTS </h1>

  </div>
  <div id="container">
 <table width="420" align="center">
 <form method="POST" action="refresh.php">
 <tr>
    <td>Choose Position</td>
    <td><SELECT name="monthReport" id="monthReport" onchange="form.submit()">
     <OPTION VALUE="select">select
     < ?php 
     //loop through all table rows
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($positions)){
     echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 

    }
    ?>
   </SELECT></td>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('month').value = "<?php echo $_POST['monthReport'];?>";
</script>
<?php 
echo '<div id="gitna">';
echo $monthReport;
 echo '</div>';
?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){echo $candidate_name_1;} ?>:<br>
<img src="images/candidate-1.gif"
width='<?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){ if ($candidate_2 || 
$candidate_1 || $candidate_3 || $candidate_4 || $candidate_5!= 0){echo(100*round($candidate_1/($candidate_2+$candidate_1+$candidate_3+$candidate_4+$candidate_5),5));}} ?>'
 height='20'>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){ if ($candidate_2 || 
$candidate_1 || $candidate_3 ||$candidate_4 || $candidate_5!= 0)

{echo(100*round($candidate_1/($candidate_2+$candidate_1+$candidate_3+$candidate_4+$candidate_5),5));}} ?>% of <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){echo $totalvotes;} ?> total votes
<br>    votes <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){ echo $candidate_1;} ?>
<br>
<br>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){ echo $candidate_name_2;} ?>:<br>
    <img src="images/candidate-2.gif"
width='<?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){ if ($candidate_2 || $candidate_1 || $candidate_3 || $candidate_4 || $candidate_5!= 0){echo(100*round($candidate_2/($candidate_2+$candidate_1+$candidate_3+$candidate_4+$candidate_5),5));}} ?>'
height='20'>

  <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){if ($candidate_5 || $candidate_4 || $candidate_3 || $candidate_2 || $candidate_1!=0){echo(100*round($candidate_5/($candidate_5+$candidate_4+$candidate_3+$candidate_2+$candidate_1),5));}} ?>% of <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){echo $totalvotes;} ?> total votes
  <br>votes <?php if(isset($_POST['monthReport'])){echo $candidate_5;} ?>
  <br>
  <br>


<br>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: the error is just when the data in database is empty it shows error "undefine" but when it have data in database it works fine too in mysqli. But in mysql it works perfectly with no errors even though the data in my db are empty

Comment: Don't fetch like that. Loop the fetch and just assign in the loop. If there are no results don't fetch at all, and don't use the variable. Also parameterize your query. If you have multiple variables like `$name_` + `X` you should probably be using an array.

Comment: is there something to do with fetch_assoc()? for having a null data?

Comment: because it works fine when im using mysql and error in mysqli

Comment: The error is the `undefined` message or something else?

Comment: all error is undefined sir

Comment: If the row does not exist your `$candidate_name_5` is null. Test for `isset($candidate_name_5)`, not just truthiness.

Comment: Naming variables `$row1` until `$row12` indicates serious design issues. You are, for instance, better off using an array, to start with. You could use a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Answer (score -1):

i just add

```
 error_reporting(1);
```

and everything works fine now

Comment: This is more or less bypassing PHP's warnings about coding issues, rather than fixing them. You should instead set the error reporting to `E_ALL` and fix the real issues.